# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite - Redirect from http to https for account controller but from https to http for everything else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, url-rewriting

I've found bits and pieces of what I need to make this work, but haven't been able to bring everything together into a workable solution.

I am working on an intranet site, and want to secure *just the logon and logoff actions on my account controller with https. I have the certificate installed correctly, and can successfully redirect traffic to these controller actions to https using a UrlRewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^account/logon$|^account/logoff$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Now, however, I also want to redirect *all of the rest of my site's requests (other than traffic to the two actions) back to http. I'm not interested in debating the merits of this approach, as I have what I consider valid reasons for wanting to redirect back out of https to http.

I've tried writing some code in the Actions to achieve this, but am having major issues with this. I don't know if it is because I'm working with two load-balanced servers or what, but anything I try just gives me a "too many redirects" error message.

So, two questions:

1. Is it better to use a UrlRewrite rule to redirect out of https or a controller actions?
2. Does anyone have a working code example or something that can at least get me started down the right path?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never. This might help you or someone else.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP">
        <match url="secureDir/(.*)" negate="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
      </rule>

      <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="secureDir/(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
      </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have a bit of a challenge here insofar as non-page resources -- how are you referencing images and stylesheets?

As for the question at hand, I think you want to force this upstream of the web servers, such as on the load balancer. I would also backstop the account controller by adding a RequireHttps attribute.

Finally, remember that even if the login process is secured, if that cookie is not transmitted over HTTPS you can easily end up with a firesheep like scenario.

Comment: Yes, we configured the load balancer to force everything to https, but this presented problems when integrating resources from externally hosted services that don't support https. I have been told by the group that manages our data center that they cannot selectively enforce https for different parts of applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code [here](http://lukesampson.com/post/471548689/entering-and-exiting-https-with-asp-net-mvc) which lets you control this with attributes.

MVC already has a [RequireHttps] attribute which you would apply to your logon/logoff pages. My code extends this approach and gives you an additional [ExitHttpsIfNotRequired] attribute. With this attribute applied to your base controller, when you try to access any action with HTTPS that doesn't have [RequireHttps], it will redirect you to HTTP.

Comment: OK, I just implemented this, but I'm getting the following error: "The page isn't redirecting properly" and "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete" when I try to hit an https page that should redirect back to http.

Comment: More information: I stepped into the FilterAttribute, and the URL string appears to be correct (not https).

Comment: Could it be something else redirecting back to HTTPS and causing a redirect loop, like a leftover URL rewrite rule or your load balancer?

Comment: So it is definitely not server configuration, because I can go directly to each server and the redirect works fine. This means it has something to do with the load balancer. Our data center staff swear that the load balancer cannot selectively implement https on individual pages (it is all or nothing), so this has to have something to do with the load balancing itself. I'll post back here when I figure out what is going on.